# Informix defining an INTERVAL with a parameter

Tags: informix

I am doing the following in Informix to delete rows more than 20 seconds old.

```
delete from sometable
where someDateColumn < (current - interval (20) second to second);
```

However, I want to make the interval configurable in a stored procedure, but I can't do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE i_hate_informix (prm_timeframe int)
    DELETE   sometable
    WHERE    someDateColumn < (current - interval (prm_timeframe) second to second);
END PROCEDURE;
```

Comment: Seems a bit harsh. It probably doesn't hate you. The solution you've found is easier than mucking around with explicit INTERVAL data types anyway.

Comment: Ok, "Hate" is probably too strong. Compared to SQL Server though it's a ---- pain in the -----.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Interval can not be defined dynamically with a variable. But you can use "units second" so my procedure becomes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE i_hate_informix (prm_timeframe int)
   DELETE   sometable
   WHERE    someDateColumn < (current - prm_timeframe units second);
END PROCEDURE;
```